# How to combine multiple disks to act as one larger one?

Tags: amazon-ec2, raid

In EC2 the `i2.2xlarge` (or `i2.4xlarge`) instance type come with `2x800 GB SSD` (or `4x800 GB SSD`) for instance storage.

Is there a way (using RAID?) to make these separate disks be treated as a single larger `1600 GB` (or `3200 GB`) disk? How? And are there any important reason *not* to do this?

Comment: What OS?  On Linux I might be tempted to put them all in an LVM volume group.  On Windows, maybe storage spaces.

Comment: Have you considered the Elastic Block Store instead of using the attached devices?  They're portable, interchangeable and you can grow and shrink them easily.

Comment: @Zoredache on Ubuntu. It sounds like "RAID 0" may answer my question but was hoping for a confirmation and more of a detailed explanation.

Comment: @Darvanen Want to stick with instance storage with SSDs for maximum performance for MongoDB and/or Elasticsearch, which both can handle the replication/redundancy.

Comment: I've also seen that e.g. Elasticsearch lets you avoid this problem with the ability to use multiple data folders http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup-dir-layout.html

Comment: The data on your instances storage volumes will be lost if your EC2 instance is stopped and restarted. Does your data need to persist past such an event or is it OK to lose the data?

Comment: Yeah that is OK.

Answer (score 3):

Zoredache answered it quite well there. Answering the last question: You will be increasing the probability of failure in a big way since the failure of just one of the devices will make the whole virtual disk fail. That's why most of us use RAID 10.